# Zurb Foundation 4 Clearing Lightbox Thumbnails in Block Grid

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use Foundation 4's Clearing Lightbox in a block grid like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="large-9 columns">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3 clearing-thumbs" data-clearing>
            <li><a href="image1.jpg"><img src="image1_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="image2.jpg"><img src="image2_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="image3.jpg"><img src="image3_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="image4.jpg"><img src="image4_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="image5.jpg"><img src="image5_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="image6.jpg"><img src="image6_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="image7.JPG"><img src="image7_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="image8.JPG"><img src="image8_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="image9.JPG"><img src="image9_lg.jpg" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The layout on my laptop screen displays the images in a 3-column grid, which is what I want (and a 2-column grid when the window is made much narrower to simulate mobile). When I click on an image, it does load the Clearing Lightbox, however the "thumbnail" images are still in the block grid at the bottom of the lightbox screen. So there are only three full thumbnail images shown and you can see a partial second row of thumbnails below them. (Screenshot [here](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/44fg3/b408) from Google Chrome.)

How can I fix the thumbnail images so either 1) they all show up in a row, or 2) just the active one is shown, or 3) no thumbnails are shown below the large image?

I am fairly new to Foundation, and I appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was reported https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2696. Although claimed to be fixed in 5.1, I still ran into the issue.

I used the suggestion by Michael Fillier to remedy this issue:

```
/***** Fix Block Grid and Clearing Compatibility *****/
[class*="block-grid-"] li {
    margin-right:0!important;
}
.clearing-blackout li {
    clear:inherit!important;
}
```

> First line removes the margin added to the li's by clearing. Second
>   line removes clearing for the thumbs in the lightbox view.

Answer (score 1):

I corresponded with Foundation Support, and they suggested that I add this to my stylesheet to hide the thumbnails altogether:

`.clearing-blackout ul {display:none !important;}`

I then went back to the default Clearing lightbox syntax as shown in the docs:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3" data-clearing>
    <li><a href="{portfolio_image_large}"><img src="{portfolio_image_small}" data-caption="{portfolio_image_caption}" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="{portfolio_image_large}"><img src="{portfolio_image_small}" data-caption="{portfolio_image_caption}" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="{portfolio_image_large}"><img src="{portfolio_image_small}" data-caption="{portfolio_image_caption}" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="{portfolio_image_large}"><img src="{portfolio_image_small}" data-caption="{portfolio_image_caption}" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="{portfolio_image_large}"><img src="{portfolio_image_small}" data-caption="{portfolio_image_caption}" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, when I click on one of the small images in the block grid it pulls up the correct large image in the Clearing lightbox. The space for the carousel was still relegated though the carousel was not displayed, so I added this code to make the large image fill up more of the screen:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
.clearing-assembled .clearing-container .visible-img {
    height: 95%;
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful to someone else. Thanks to Mark at Foundation Support and to the other poster who got me part way there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, and I found a good CSS fix on Foundation's  Github page.

You should add the following line to your CSS, and all thumbnails will show up in one row as expected.

```
div.clearing-container .large-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
clear: none; }
```

Here is the solution in detail: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2825

Answer (score 0):

Foundation doesn't do this out of the box with presentationaly classes alone, but you can create the same effect by hiding the clearing gallery and adding a little javascript/jquery.

Create your block-grid with simple images and anchor tags with a custom class, in this case `img-spawn-gallery`

Then create your clearing gallery, but use the `hide` presentational class so it is not displayed.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
      <p>Some other content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-9 columns">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3">
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="img-spawn-gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
        </ul>

      <ul id="my-gallery" class="clearing-thumbs hide" data-clearing>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.placehold.it/900x900?text=gallery"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300&text=thumb" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in JavaScript with Zepto or jQuery you can override the behavior of the anchor tags so that they click on the first img of your hidden clearing gallery. since only the thumbnails are hidden the rest of it works properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".img-spawn-gallery").click(function() {
    $("#my-gallery li a :first").trigger('click');
  });
});
```

UPDATE 10/16/13: This came through as an edit but should probably be added as a comment. I am adding it here as it might be useful for those who are facing this issue. Anonymous poster, feel free to take the credit in the comments.

> To add the ability to jump to the image you have clicked, edit the
>   Javascript like so:

```
 $(".img-spawn-gallery").click(function() 
  {
    index = $(this).parents("li").index();
    $("#my-gallery li a :eq("+index+")").trigger('click');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! How will the `a.img-spawn-gallery` links know which image to launch in the lightbox? It seems like `#my-gallery li a :first` would just pick the first one every time? I will give it a try, and maybe it will make sense to me then.  :)

Comment: This is working great but, as I suspected, always opens the Lightbox to the first image. Is there a way to tell it to open to the clicked image? I am generating the code dynamically through ExpressionEngine, so there could be a variable number of images. Thanks!

Comment: @AmyWitty I updated the post with an answer to your last question that came from an anonymous user as a post update. Hope this helps to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to "3) no thumbnails are shown below the large image"

In Foundation 5 I changed the following default from:

```
$clearing-active-img-height: 75%;
```

to:

```
$clearing-active-img-height: 100%;
```

No thumbnails are shown below the large image.